# Add a column that locate the value in column J (10th column) and row number specific to the range adress referenced in the code

Tags: excel, vba

let me give you an exmple of what i would like to achieve.  For instance: if the range adress is "N40:FB40", i wantthe .Cells(5).Value and .Cells(5).Offset(1).Value lines to retrieve the value from row 40 and column J (the 10th column) for each range address. the strucutre should be the same for each range adress, for instance, if the range adress is now "N52:FB52", retrieve the value from row 52 and column J (the 10th column). thanks a lot!!!

```
Dim RangeValues As Object 'global (or could use Static inside the event handler)
Dim startTime

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim elapsedTime As Double ' Stores the elapsed time
    Dim logSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oldValues As Variant, newValues As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long, numColumns As Long
    Dim i As Long, LogRanges, el

    'assuming all ranges to be logged are single-row and >1 cell...
    LogRanges = Array("N20:FB20", "N21:FB21", "N22:FB22", "N24:FB24", "N26:FB26", "N30:FB30", "N31:FB31", "N32:FB32", "N33:FB33", "N34:FB34", "N35:FB35", "N38:FB38", "N40:FB40", "N42:FB42", "N44:FB44", "N48:FB48", "N49:FB49", "N50:FB50")

    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "G11" 'G11 was selected
            ' Start the stopwatch and capture old values
            startTime = Now
            Set RangeValues = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For Each el In LogRanges 'capture current values from each range
                With Me.Range(el)
                    RangeValues(.Address) = .Value
                End With
            Next el
        Case "H11" 'H11 was selected
            ' Stop the stopwatch, capture new values, and log the information
            Set logSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log - Ratio")
            rowNum = logSheet.Cells(logSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 3

          ' Assuming the target sheet name is "TargetSheet" (replace with actual sheet name)
            Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ratios sommaire")


          For Each el In LogRanges
                With Me.Range(el)
                    oldValues = RangeValues(.Address)
                    newValues = .Value
                End With
                numColumns = UBound(oldValues, 2)
                With logSheet.Rows(rowNum)
                    .Cells(1).Value = startTime
                    .Cells(1).Offset(1).Value = Now
                    .Cells(2).Resize(2).Value = Application.UserName
                    .Cells(3).Resize(2).Value = el 'range address
                    .Cells(4).Value = "OLD"
                    .Cells(5).Value =  `Retrieve value from row xxxx and column 10
                    .Cells(6).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = oldValues
                    .Cells(4).Offset(1).Value = "NEW"
                    .Cells(5).Offset(1).Value = `Retrieve value from row xxxx and column 10
                    .Cells(6).Offset(1).Resize(1, numColumns).Value = newValues

                End With
                rowNum = rowNum + 3
            Next el


    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Something like `.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(Me.Range(el).Row, "J").Value`?

Comment: I tried, The output results in an empty cell. I don't know why.... BigBen